# Can I register MVP Presenter inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, mvp, android-mvp

I've been following MVP design pattern provided by [Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/)  to refactor my application. I have one MainActivity and many Fragments and it seems little be messy for me to create an activity for every fragment, so I've been thinking to register presenter in fragment. What I'm seeing is that every fragment register its own presenter, but I'm not sure how much wrong it is... :)

So here is my Presenter:

```
public class FirstPresenter implements FirstContract.Presenter {
    private final FirstContract.View mView;

    public FirstPresenter(FirstContract.View view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Start");
    }
}
```

And here is my Fragment:

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements FirstContract.View {
    private FirstContract.Presenter mPresenter;

@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container
            , Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
// I register firstFragment's presenter here.
mPresenter = new FirstPresenter(this);
...
```

So my question is, is this right way? Can I register Presenter into Fragment instead in Activity? And if it is not the right way, is there some good example to handle MVP with one activity and multiple fragments?

Thank you guys,
BR!

Comment: In the example code in the Android Blueprint repository, you'll see `Presenters` being created inside the `Activity`, but the registration will be done inside the `Fragment` as well. See the `TaskDetailActivity` for instance: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/taskdetail/TaskDetailActivity.java - we're using MVP in our app as well and we do the registration the same way. I don't see any issue in doing it like this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you can see in **Google's** samples (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture), `Activities` create `Presenters`. Also `Views` attach to `Activity` and `Presenters` get views (`Fragments`) as parameter.

After `Fragment` transaction committed or `Fragment` (view) state restored `Presenters` get created and take `Fragments` (views) as parameter than call

```
view.setPresenter(T presenter);
```

methods of views and `Presenters` get registered to view.

I think creating `Presenter` in `Fragment` is not a good practice. First of all they are **separate layers**. This is illegal for **Separation of concerns**. And second, if you create presenter in `Fragment`, you bind your Presenter's life to view's `LifeCycle` and when `Fragment` is destroyed and recreated, you create a new presenter but they're different layers.

**The model** is an interface defining the data to be displayed or otherwise acted upon in the user interface.

**The presenter** acts upon the model and the view. It retrieves data from repositories (the model), and formats it for display in the view.

**The view** is a passive interface that displays data (the model) and routes user commands (events) to the presenter to act upon that data.

So `Activity` can act as an `overall controller` which creates the `Presenters` and `Views` and connect them.

[image]

If we talk about your question, yes you can register presenter in fragment. But you should avoid creating presenters in fragments which you use as a view.

But there're lot's of different approaches about MVP pattern in Android community like below.
https://plus.google.com/communities/114285790907815804707

Why activities are not ui elements?
http://www.techyourchance.com/activities-android/

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer! Since you seems like experienced developer do you have solution how to solve problem with one Activity and multiple fragments?

Comment: as i mentioned in my answer, if you need multiple fragments in same activity, you can let activity create a new fragment commit fragment transaction, create presenter and connect them. but i did not see an implementation like this in google samples. they implement 1 activity - 1 fragment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using one single Activity to host multiple Fragments and you are also using Dagger 2 to inject the presenter you need you can inject each presenter to each Fragment directly.

### My use case story

I'm doing a project with architecture since some months from now since I found out about Android jetpack Navigation Component, I started to migrate all my app views into this pattern.

So, I came across a lot of refactoring doing the process and I was at this situation of don't know what to do with this situation.

Since I used Dagger 2 from the start point to inject my presenters into my Activities, this won't change much doing the same but with Fragments.

I came across the same repository to check how the architecture was supposed to follow with Fragments, which is indeed a good way to do the instantiation of the presenter inside the host Activity if you have only 1 Fragment as a child.

The thing is that if I need to have multiple Fragments inside one host Activity I should make an instance of each presenter and pass it through my FragmentManager inside each Fragment and that I think is not what I was looking at since it adds multiple instantiations of the presenter from the Host Activity.

This leads to one case, having multiple instances inside my host activity for all presenters, and also some interfaces to handle the detaching of the jobs/views if needed.

One simple way to do it with multiple fragments is just not thinking about the host activity and inject the presenters inside each Fragment itself.

Since doing this with Dagger, it makes the injection cleaner.

Take a look at a simple example

```
class MainMenuActivity : BaseActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        inflateMainFragment(savedInstanceState)
    }

      override fun getLayout(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_main_menu
    }

    fun inflateMainFragment(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            val fragment = MainMenuFragment()
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment)
                .commit()
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see , here I dont have any instantiation of any presenters all my navigation should need. Instead, I just inject each presenter I need inside each Fragment

```
class MapsFragment: BaseMapFragment(), MapContract.MapView {

    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: MapsPresenter

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_paseo,container,false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (requireActivity().application as YawpApplication).getAppComponent()?.inject(this)
        presenter.attachView(this)
        setupToolbar()
        setupMap()
    }
}
```

And making use of the Fragments lifecycle, you can detach all your Fragments views in `onDestroyView()` method, and also save some memory space when the garbage collector runs.

```
 override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        presenter.detachView()
        presenter.detachJob()
    }
```

I have found at the official google repo a question that helped me understand it better.

You can check it [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/issues/274)